# Hosting my domain name in 12.04 web server

Tags: 12.04, hosts

In sites-available I created a new file from the default file and changed paths. 
In sites-enabled I created a sym link. 
In hosts I added the new domain after 127.0.0.1 localhost
restarted apache but my web sites does not show outside, only on my local machine
What's wrong?
Fero

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment, you'd have to add the desired domain name to your DNS server and configure it to point to your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My DNS servers are in network/interfaces with the static IP